# Scala XSD library

Tags: scala, xsd

What are the options for querying XSD files in Scala.

The standard XML library is of course one option, but has anyone made a library for working with xsds specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has one, which you can integrate, according to [this article](http://sean8223.blogspot.com/2009/09/xsd-validation-in-scala.html).